# SwiftUI Previews: Failed to build scheme (Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, x86-64

I have an existing Xcode project that I am trying to add SwiftUI elements to. The project has a bunch of Cocoapods and other Frameworks included and when I build it to my device, it works fine. However, I am trying to get the SwiftUI Preview to work within Xcode and when I build it there, I get the following error:

> Link Literally (x86_64): ld: warning: directory not found for option
> ...[GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (pod), Giphy (pod), DeepAR (framework)]
> ...building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file
> built for iOS-arm64
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "*OBJC_CLASS*$_CameraController"...

It's my understanding that this issue is relating to some of the 3rd party frameworks that we have that are not being capable of running on the simulator. I've already updated the Pods and have not had any luck.

I've already tried 'Build Active Architecture Only' -> YES, but the Preview still builds with all of these pods/frameworks included. The SwiftUIView that I am trying to preview does NOT include/need any of these pods/frameworks, so **I'm wondering if there is a way to make the Preview build only for the current SwiftUIView file that I'm working in?**

Note: the pods/frameworks are required for this app and we cannot remove them entirely.

Comment: Some things you could try...
 - Make the linked frameworks optional. Maybe the errors won't stop compilation then?
 - Extract the SwiftUI files you're using into a separate module, and import that module into your main project. Then, when you want to use Canvas, you don't have to worry with the module linking against the incompatible pods.